# Onclick event in For loop in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a series of data that contains some objects in one array(json file) and it will be shown in React. The main problem is that the value of `index_` in `onClick={e => this.handelruleRoom(e, element.families[j], index)}` function  in **for loop** always shows the last one. For example `lenfamilies` is 3 , when ever I click `<span  key={index} onClick={e => this.handelruleRoom(e, element.families[j], index)}>Click</span>` with `key=1`in console the value of `index_` is 3.

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [],
        DetailsInfo: {},
        text:{}
    }
}
render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    const renderInfo = data.map((item, i) => {
        return (
            <div class="item">
                <div class="moreInfo" onClick={e => this.showDiv(e, item, i)}>
                    <span>show more data</span>
                </div>
                    <div class="table">{this.state.DetailsInfo[i]}</div>
                </div>
        )
    })
    return <div>{renderInfo}</div>;
}
showDiv = (e, element, i) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        DetailsInfo: { ...prevState.DetailsInfo, [i]: this.renderDetails(element, i) },
    }))
}
renderDetails(element,i){
     let lenfamilies = element.families.length 
     var indents =[];
         var index=0;
     for(var j = 0 ;j <lenfamilies;j++){
         var numF = i;
         var numS = j;
         var stingF = numF.toString();
         var stingS = numS.toString();
         index= stingF+stingS
         indents.push(<div>
             <span  key={index} onClick={e => this.handelrule(e, element.families[j], index)}>Click</span>
             <span  class="text" key={index}>{this.state.text[index]}</span></div>
         )
     }
     return(
       indents
       )
     }
handelrule = (e, element, index) => {
console.log(index)
 this.setState( prevState => ({
     text: { ...prevState.text, [index]:   'test'},
     })) 
  }
}
 ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("Result"));
```

Comment: Hi @Prakash Sharma.I use`let` instead of `var` for `j ` variable. but there is no different;|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a `function` inside a loop. You can avoid the for loop altogether by using `forEach` or `map` method like this

```
lenfamilies.forEach((fml, j) => {
         var numF = i;
         var numS = j;
         var stingF = numF.toString();
         var stingS = numS.toString();
         index= stingF+stingS
         indents.push(<span  key={index} onClick={e => this.handelrule(e, element.families[j], index)}>Click</span>
         )
     }
);
```

Or you can use `let` instead of `var` for `j`

```
for(let j = 0 ;j <lenfamilies;j++){
    ...
    indents.push(<span  key={index} onClick={e => this.handelrule(e, element.families[j], index)}>Click</span>)
}
```

**UPDATE:-**

For `index`, you can take `index` declaration inside the loop and use `let` for `index` too.

```
for(let j = 0 ;j <lenfamilies;j++){
    let index = 0;
    ....
```

Comment: Using `let` instead of `var` for `j` did not solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks alot @Prakash Sharma. There is another issue. Can I ask you?

Comment: @bita If issue is completely different, it would be better to ask another dedicated question.

Comment: It is about this question.

Comment: Could you please take a look on my code. I want by clicking `onClick={e => this.handelrule(e, element.families[j], index)}` the text of `<span  class="text" key={index}>{this.state.text[index]}</span>` be   `test` and  `test` is going to be dynamic. I put  `test` just as testing, but does not set.

Comment: @bita That is because you are not updating `DetailsInfo` state on click. You should call the `renderDetail` function on `render` time instead of setting it in `DetailsInfo`. It would be better to ask other question as there will be more hands to help you out.